# Incorrect result from getpid() for grandchild with vfork() and -lpthread

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, fork, vfork

In one of the special cases shown below, `getpid()` for the grandchild created with `vfork()` returns the PID of the parent process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  if(vfork()) { /* parent */
    printf("parent pid = %d\n", getpid());
    exit(0);
  } else {
    if(vfork()) { /* child */
      printf("child pid = %d\n", getpid());
      exit(0);
    } else { /* grandchild */
      printf("grandchild pid = %d\n", getpid());
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Compiled as `gcc main.c`, this works as expected:

```
grandchild pid = 12241
child  pid = 12240
parent pid = 12239
```

Compiled as `gcc main.c -lpthread`, the grandchild PID is incorrect:

```
grandchild pid = 12431
child pid = 12432
parent pid = 12431
```

Any clues why? Is this one of the undefined behavior cases?

With `ps` and `strace`, I can see the correct PID. BTW, the same example code works fine with `fork()`, i.e. correct `getpid()` with or without `-lpthread`.

Comment: I fail to see how linking libpthread could make a difference here. Apart from that, you perform forbidden actions after `vfork()`, hence the results are unstable and may vary with slight, seemingly unrelated, changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getpid` is not one of the two operations you're permitted to perform after `vfork` in the child; the only two are `execve` and `_exit`. It happens that glibc caches the process's pid in userspace, and does not update this cache on `vfork` (since it would modify the parent's cached value, and since it's not needed since valid code can't observe the result); that's the mechanism of the behavior you're seeing. The caching behavior differs slightly with `-lpthread` linked. But the underlying reason is that your code is invalid.

Pretty much, **don't use `vfork`**. There's basically nothing you can do with it.

Comment: Interesting, that caching behaviour change with libpthread linked. Do you have any reading for that?

Comment: You'd have to read the glibc source (for the version you're using; it may have changed). It's not a documented behavior because it's not observable in code without UB.

Comment: Yes, I cannot reproduce the behaviour at all, so this does not apply to my version. But it seems to be present in the OPs version (at least its a plausible explanation for it)

Comment: @Ctx it's undefined behavior, why would you expect it to have any sense or to be able to reproduce it?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli The "undefined behaviour" is not an explanation for what you see, it is just the reason, why it is - according to the specifications - _valid_ what you see. Yet, there is a reason for a specific behaviour and in this case - that linking libpthread changes the getpid() caching behaviour of glibc - is interesting (at least to me). If you don't care about the specific reasons for the observed behaviour, that's ok for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual page for `vfork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html):

> The  `vfork()`  function  has  the  same effect as `fork(2)`, except that **the behavior is undefined** if the
>   process created by `vfork()` either modifies any data other than a variable of type `pid_t` used to store the return  value
>   from `vfork()`, or returns from the function in which `vfork()` was called, or calls any other function before successfully
>   calling `_exit(2)` or one of the `exec(3)` family of functions.

It's not very nicely worded, but what this is saying is that the only things that a child process can do after `vfork()` are:

- Check the return value.
- Call one of the `exec*()` family of functions.
- Call `_exit()`.

This is because:

> `vfork()`  is a special case of `clone(2)`.  It is used to create new processes **without copying the page tables of the parent process**.  It may be useful in performance-sensitive applications where a child is created  which  then  immediately
>   issues an `execve(2)`.

In other words, the intended use of `vfork()` is only to create children that will execute other programs through `exec*()`, making this faster than a normal `fork()` because the page table of the parent is not duplicated in the child (since it's going to be replaced by `exec*()` anyway). Even then though, `vfork()` only has a real advantage if this kind of operation needs to be performed multiple times. Since parent memory is not copied, accessing it in any way is undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that **all** valid uses of `vfork` are subsumed by `posix_spawn`, which is safe to use.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE well, `vfork` was available from 2.0.112 and `posix_spawn` from 2.2, so... depends. But yeah, it's an ugly syscall anyway.

Comment: 2.0.112 and 2.2 of what? Linux? `posix_spawn` isn't a syscall so it's a matter of library support not kernel.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE of glibc of course (vfork is a syscall)

Answer (score 0):

here is the requirements for `vfork()`

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <unistd.h>

   pid_t vfork(void);
```

Notice the OPs posted code fails to include the needed header files.

Comment: Indeed failure to include `unistd.h` (`sys/types.h` is not relevant though) is another cause of UB (or rather even a constraint violation that should be a compile-time failure). However this is not the mechanism of the failure OP is seeing.